# Ball speed measuring with OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, performance, opencv, tracking, motion

I need to measure the ball speed of a ping pong ball when it is shot out of a ping pong ball shoot machine.

We decided to measure its speed with video motion tracking. 
With **Python** and **OpenCV** we got to the point that we could **track the ball**.
The next step is to **measure its speed**. But we have no clue how to do it.

```
# import the necessary packages
from collections import deque
import numpy as np
import argparse

import cv2

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video",
    help="path to the (optional) video file")
ap.add_argument("-b", "--buffer", type=int, default=64,
    help="max buffer size")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# define the lower and upper boundaries of the "green"
# ball in the HSV color space, then initialize the
# list of tracked points
greenLower = (51, 60, 60)
greenUpper = (64, 255, 255)
pts = deque(maxlen=args["buffer"])

# if a video path was not supplied, grab the reference
# to the webcam
if not args.get("video", False):
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# otherwise, grab a reference to the video file
else:
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])

# keep looping
while True:
    # grab the current frame
    (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()

    # if we are viewing a video and we did not grab a frame,
    # then we have reached the end of the video
    if args.get("video") and not grabbed:
        break

    # resize the frame, blur it, and convert it to the HSV
    # color space

    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (11, 11), 0)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # construct a mask for the color "green", then perform
    # a series of dilations and erosions to remove any small
    # blobs left in the mask
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, greenLower, greenUpper)
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)

    # find contours in the mask and initialize the current
    # (x, y) center of the ball
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
    center = None

    # only proceed if at least one contour was found
    if len(cnts) > 0:
        # find the largest contour in the mask, then use
        # it to compute the minimum enclosing circle and
        # centroid
        c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
        ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        M = cv2.moments(c)
        center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))

        # only proceed if the radius meets a minimum size
        if radius > 10:
            # draw the circle and centroid on the frame,
            # then update the list of tracked points
            cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius),
                (0, 255, 255), 2)
            cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)



    # show the frame to our screen
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # if the 'q' key is pressed, stop the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

# cleanup the camera and close any open windows
camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: rate = distance / time.  You should have already written code for that much, with an attempt to produce valid output.

You need to find the difference in position between two frames.  Translate that to real-world distance.  We can't do that for you -- this is dependent on your video environment.  Divide that distance by the time between the two frames.  The result is the ball's average speed over that time interval.

Comment: Unless the video has a high frame rate, you're going to have to deal with images where the ball is blurry. Very blurry. Where are you going to measure from when it'll be difficult to detect the real centre of the ball? That's something you're going to have to solve!